# Disable Redis autoconfiguration in Micronout

Tags: redis, micronaut, lettuce

How can I disable Redis (Lettuce) autoconfiguration in Micronaut framework?

It wants to do all the configuration on the code side, example:

```java
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient
  .create("redis://password@1.2.3.4:6379/");
```

Currently my manual configuration works, but in addition, I receive an error related to the automatic configuration:

```
ERROR [i.m.m.h.i.HealthResult HealthResult.java:119] Health indicator [redis(Primary)] reported exception: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379
io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:242)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:206)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:191)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.health.RedisHealthIndicator.lambda$getResult$2(RedisHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:378)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:363)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableToListSingle.subscribeActual(FlowableToListSingle.java:57)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable.subscribeActual(SingleToFlowable.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:236)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:124)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask.monitor(HealthMonitorTask.java:98)
    at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.$HealthMonitorTaskDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.inject.DelegatingExecutableMethod.invoke(DelegatingExecutableMethod.java:76)
```

In Spring Boot I can use en adnotation:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {...})
```